# Changing root after connecting with a non-root user in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, root, sudo, sccm

I have a lil' issue while scipting. I have script which will install agents called SCCM and TrendMicro. After I logged in with a sudo priviledge user, I wanna run commands with root user in script. I don't know how to do. I tried sudo for some command which wants root priv. But I get the ***"sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo"*** message. So I want to login with sudo priv. user than change to root and run all the commands.

NOTE:I just add the SCCM installation. After i figured out this, I'll add the TM installation commands in $SCRIPT.

```
> #!/bin/bash USERNAME=user HOSTS="host1 host2" 
  SCRIPT="mkdir /tmp/SCCM; wget -O /tmp/SCCM/ccm-Universalx64.tar
> ftp://local/pub/SW/SCCM/ccm-Universalx64.tar; wget -O
> /tmp/SCCM/install ftp://local/pub/SW/SCCM/install; chmod 755
> /tmp/SCCM/*; cd /tmp/SCCM; /tmp/SCCM/install -mp another_host
> -sitecode MGR ccm-Universalx64.tar;  /etc/init.d/ccmexecd stop; /etc/init.d/ccmexecd start" for HOSTNAME in ${HOSTS} ; do
>     ssh -l ${USERNAME} ${HOSTNAME} "${SCRIPT}"
```

done 
exit

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to the `/etc/sudoers` of the host your are connecting to?

[This blog](https://www.shell-tips.com/2014/09/08/sudo-sorry-you-must-have-a-tty-to-run-sudo/) and the [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange Website](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122616/why-do-i-need-a-tty-to-run-sudo-if-i-can-sudo-without-a-password) point to changing the line in `/etc/sudoers` from `Defaults requiretty` to `Defaults !requiretty` OR to use the `-t` or `-tt` options to ssh which spawns a pseudo-terminal on the remote side. Beware side effects (see the second above listed link for details).